# Poor performance on digit recognition with CNN trained on MNIST dataset

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

I trained a `CNN` (on `tensorflow`) for digit recognition using `MNIST` dataset.
Accuracy on test set was close to `98%`.

I wanted to predict the digits using data which I created myself and the results were bad.

**What I did to the images written by me?**

I segmented out each digit and converted to grayscale and resized the image into `28x28` and fed to the model.

How come that I get such low accuracy on my data set where as such high accuracy on test set?

Are there other modifications that i'm supposed to make to the images?

**EDIT:**

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByP5h3h0_JHNR2pnZEZSblNfWGM) to the images and some examples:

[image: image of digit 7]
[image: digit 5]
[image: digit 9]
[image: digit 6]

Comment: Could you provide us some samples from your dataset?

Comment: Upload your image here.

Comment: @SilverSlash I added the links to the images

Comment: The images have gray background?

Comment: @kvmanohar Please upload examples of both your images and the MNIST dataset, not just the links

Comment: what happens if you feed in your own handwritten digits with a white/black background (whatever colour background your MNIST data has)?

Comment: @Simon The predictions are all wrong

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida I don't have the images of MNIST dataset but the data was downloaded from yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Comment: @SilverSlash Yes, the images have gray background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding bugs and obvious errors, my guess would be that your problem is that you are capturing your hand written digits in a way that is too different from your training set.

When capturing your data you should try to mimic as much as possible the process used to create the MNIST dataset:

From the [oficial MNIST dataset website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/):

> The original black and white (bilevel) images from NIST were size
>   normalized to fit in a 20x20 pixel box while preserving their aspect
>   ratio. The resulting images contain grey levels as a result of the
>   anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm. the
>   images were centered in a 28x28 image by computing the center of mass
>   of the pixels, and translating the image so as to position this point
>   at the center of the 28x28 field.

If your data has a different processing in the training and test phases then your model is not able to generalize from the train data to the test data.

So I have two advices for you:

1. Try to capture and process your digit images so that they look as similar as possible to the MNIST dataset;
2. Add some of your examples to your training data to allow your model to train on images similar to the ones you are classifying;

Answer (score 1):

For those still have a hard time with the poor quality of CNN based models for MNIST:

https://github.com/christiansoe/mnist_draw_test

Normalization was the key.